# How to view folder or directory size of email from cpanel in PHP script?

Tags: php, email, root, cpanel, dir

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` = /home/username/public_html

how to get `/home/mail` directory in PHP?

Comment: There is no variable for that. You have to know that location ahead of time.

Comment: i want to get email size with php and display to my web. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
function folderSize ($dir)
{
    $size = 0;
    foreach (glob(rtrim($dir, '/').'/*', GLOB_NOSORT) as $each) {
        $size += is_file($each) ? filesize($each) : folderSize($each);
    }
    return $size;
}

echo folderSize('/home/username/mail/');
```

you have to check if that path is correct in your server, the example is for centos and cpanel